# Django migrations for second model

Tags: django, django-migrations

Django doesn't respond to making the migrations to the model in the new app.

I deleted the app then made a new one, but still doesn't respond. I deleted the old migration and makemigrations, Django only respond to the first model which I have done before this problem

(venv) F:\My site>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

(venv) F:\My site>python manage.py makemigrations blog
No installed app with label 'blog'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is set your new app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` of Django `settings.py`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'blog'
]
```

Comment: It works! I'm surprised cause I did the same for the old app but didn't work